# Language settings disappeared

Tags: user-profile, 2019, alternate-language

I can't find the settings to change my language preferences (SharePoint 2019 server).
It happening from September 2020 updated.
From my profile page (/person.aspx) I can't find the command to change profile information.
If I navigate to the page ("/_layouts/15/editprofile.aspx") there is no command to language settings.
It has been move?
This command in the image below so be clear
[image: language and region]

Answer (score 0):

There is a  long list of issues with non-English functionality in the September CU.  It is mentioned in the "Known Issues" section. More details are available here
https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2020/09/14/regression-in-september-2020-cu-for-sharepoint-2019-affects-sites-with-modern-ui/

Comment: the problems described in Grossner's post affect only the modern UI. are you sure is the same problem?

Comment: I don't have that CU installed because of that issue, so I can't test it.  Did you try "_layouts/15/editprofile.aspx?UserSettingsProvider=dfb95e82-8132-404b-b693-25418fdac9b6"  instead?

It's relatively rare, but do you have an alternative user profile service provider, different from the out-of-the box one?

If that's not it, you can try "_layouts/15/regionalsetng.aspx?Type=user"  This doesn't do the same thing as editing the profile, it will not sync the setting change with AD or with other site collections, but it might give some insight.

Comment: You are right. If I add the UserSettingsProvider parameter with the guid of my environment I can change the language settings. Thank you so much!

I believe that the original problem, the disappearance of the command to navigate to the profile settings modification page, is caused by some funny user that he edited page of my "mysite" environment!